# node-mysql2 query stream returns incorrect number of results

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql2

I'm querying the database periodically to extract a potentially large dataset. To do so I'm using mysql2 query streams, so I would be able to consume it via async iterator.

```js
    async* getData(startTime: Date, endTime: Date) : AsyncGenerator<any> {
        const query = `
            SELECT * FROM ${this.tableName} WHERE 1=1
            AND createdAt >= ?
            AND createdAt < ?
        `;

        const recordStream = this.connectionPool.query(query, [startTime, endTime]).stream({ highWaterMark: 1000 });
        recordStream.on("error", async (error) => { await handleStreamError(error); });

        for await (const record of recordStream) {
            yield record;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the query would return less results, or no data without throwing any errors, when compared to sequalize or other client.
The data in the DB is static at this point and doesn't change.
Node.js v14.5.0 is mysql2 2.5.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem manifests itself with Node.js v14.5.0 but not with versions 14.14.0 and above.

Comment: Any update please - has this been sorted out yet?